# Can't convert RTF to HTML using Itenso RTF

Tags: html, vb.net, rtf

I am using [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27431/Writing-Your-Own-RTF-Converter) to convert RTF to HTML.

The code is:

```
Dim rtfDocument As IRtfDocument = RtfInterpreterTool.BuildDoc(bodytxt.Text)
Dim htmlConverter As New RtfHtmlConverter(rtfDocument)
Dim html1 As String = htmlConverter.Convert()
```

But I get an error on the first line:

> a text cannot appear on root level, must be child of a group: 'abc''

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is `bodytxt.Text` valid RTF?

Comment: yest, bodytxt is a rich text box

Comment: In that case, does it work if you use use `bodytxt.Rtf` instead?

Comment: already fixed it bruh

Comment: @zackraiyan if you answered it yourself, take the time to post an answer and mark it as accepted. Otherwise this question will be useless to everyone.

Comment: But i edited the question added FIX there..is it not right ? anyway, i am adding an answer

Comment: please mark my answer as the answer to help others

Comment: No it's not right, and [SOLVED] doesn't go before the title. This isn't TomsHardware. BTW welcome to SO. Please take some time to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: i am done with taking the tour, but thanks for letting me know....Please mark my answer because i can't mark my own answer within 3 days

Comment: @zackraiyan It says clearly in the tour `The person who asked can mark one answer as "accepted".` so clearly you weren't done taking the tour.

Comment: o god, when did i say i dont know that i can mark my own answer? i can, but it gives me a notice"You can't mark your own answer within 3 days/You can mark your answer tomorrow".In case i might forget, that's why i asked you to mark it..But anyways, i will mark it tomorrow

Comment: But it is _**only you**_ that can mark it as accepted. It doesn't say anywhere in the tour that others can, thus it means _**only**_ the person who asked the question can do it. You can't mark it tomorrow either because 2 days haven't lapsed yet.

Comment: Nobody but you can mark it as the answer. Nobody expects you to know everything after less than a week on the site (but have some humility). See you around

Answer (score 0):

This is an easy fix . Changed

```
bodytxt.text
```

to

```
bodytxt.rtf
```